# What's the difference between CMTD-1 and key-committing security?

Tags: authenticated-encryption

The paper *[Efficient Schemes for Committing Authenticated Encryption](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/268.pdf)* introduces a framework for committing security notions that includes:

- CMT-1: commit to the key.
- CMT-3: commit to the key, nonce, and associated data.
- CMT-4: commit to all inputs, so the message as well.

Then there are D-notions referring to decryption for each of them (CMTD-1, CMTD-3, and CMTD-4).

However, there's a difference between CMTD-1 and 'key-committing security', which is rather confusing.

> Our CMTD-1 notion is stronger than the key-committing notion in prior
> work [4], since we allow the adversary to specify different nonces N1
> and N2. In contrast, the key-committing notion requires the two nonces
> to be the same.

Reference `[4]` refers to the paper *[How to Abuse and Fix Authenticated Encryption Without Key Commitment](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1456.pdf)*. This paper says something that sounds similar on pg. 14:

> Claim 1. If adversary A produces a winning tuple (N,A,C,T,Kcom) for
> keys K1 /= K2, then A has found a collision (on Kcom). Note that the
> claim holds even if the adversary may freely choose two different
> nonces N1 and N2 as input.

The CMT-1 UtC/generic transform looks like:

```
(commitment, subkey) = Hash(key, nonce)
ciphertext = Encrypt(subkey, nonce, associatedData, message)
return commitment || ciphertext
```

Whereas the key-committing generic transform from `[4]` looks like:

```
subkey = Hash(key, nonce1)
commitment = Hash(key, nonce1)
ciphertext = Encrypt(subkey, nonce2, associatedData, message)
return ciphertext || commitment
```

or this:

```
subkey = Hash(key)
commitment = Hash(key)
ciphertext = Encrypt(subkey, nonce, associatedData, message)
return ciphertext || commitment
```

Note that there's domain separation between the subkey/commitment derivation.

#### Questions

1. Is the difference between CMTD-1 and 'key-committing' not committing to the nonce used for encryption? If so, bit weird how CMT-1 is not just called CMT-2.
2. Wouldn't this mean there's a difference for CMT-1 as well as CMTD-1? The paper only says 'Our CMTD-1 notion'.
3. What's the impact of using the 'key-committing' approach rather than CMT-1?